# Android Studio is unable to run the Device monitor

Tags: android, android-studio

When Ever I try to run the Android Device monitor through my android studio (1.0.1). It gives me the following error.

[image]

I do not know how to resolve it . Where as my Java_Home path variable is set already. And After this error I checked it , it is indicating correct path of jre/jdk.

Please tell me how to resolve it.

Comment: You have to set `JAVA_HOME` variable for JDK (not JRE). Then, try to restart Android Studio and run monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have not set the path for your compiler, so do this:

- Go to my computer
- Then right click and go to properties
- there in the top left corner you see  Advanced System Setting ,click it
- You see a popup and click on environment variables then find PATH in System   variables ,then click it and click on edit and then paste the address of your bin folder of jdk folder where your jdk folder is located
- If you dont find the path then click new and in first text field write Path and in second copy the address.
  the address will look like something:
  **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin**
  then click ok and after then restart the Android studio in Administrator mode.

Hope this help!!